# Problems interpolating and evaluating numpy array at arbitrary points with Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to replicate some of the functionality of Matlab's interp2. I know somewhat similar questions have been asked before, but none apply to my specific case.

I have a distance map (available at this Google drive location):
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6acq_amk5e3X0Q5UG1ya1VhSlE&authuser=0

Values are normalized in the range 0-1. Size is 200 rows by 300 columns.

I can load it up with this code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
dstnc1=np.load('dstnc.npy')
```

Coordinates are defined by the next snippet:

```
xmin = 0.
xmax = 9000.
ymin = 0.
ymax = 6000.
r1,c1 = dstnc1.shape
x = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,c1)
y = np.linspace(ymin, ymax,r1)
```

I have three map points defined by vectors xnew1, ynew1 with this snippet:

```
xnew1=[3700.540199,3845.940199,3983.240199]
ynew1=[1782.8611,1769.862,1694.862]
```

I check their location with respect to the distance map with this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 16))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.imshow(dstnc1, cmap=my_cmap_r,vmin=0,vmax=0.3,
           extent=[0, 9000, 0, 6000], origin='upper')
plt.scatter(xnew1, ynew1, s=50, linewidths=0.15)
plt.show()
```

They plot in the correct location. Now I would like to extract the
distance value at those three points. I tried first `interp2d`.

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
x1 = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,c1)
y1 = np.linspace(ymin,ymax,r1)
f = interp2d(x1, y1, dstnc1, kind='cubic')
```

but when I try to evaluate with:

```
test=f(xnew1,ynew1)
```

I get this error:

```
--------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-299-d0f42e609b23> in <module>()
----> 1 test=f(xnew1,ynew1)

C:\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.pyc
in __call__(self, x, y, dx, dy)
    270                                 (self.y_min, self.y_max)))
    271
--> 272         z = fitpack.bisplev(x, y, self.tck, dx, dy)
    273         z = atleast_2d(z)
    274         z = transpose(z)

C:\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\fitpack.pyc
in bisplev(x, y, tck, dx, dy)
   1027     z,ier = _fitpack._bispev(tx,ty,c,kx,ky,x,y,dx,dy)
   1028     if ier == 10:
-> 1029         raise ValueError("Invalid input data")
   1030     if ier:
   1031         raise TypeError("An error occurred")

ValueError: Invalid input data
```

If I try `RectBivariateSpline`:

```
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline
x2 = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,r1)
y2 = np.linspace(ymin,ymax,c1)
f = RectBivariateSpline(x2, y2, dstnc1)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-302-d0f42e609b23> in <module>()
----> 1 test=f(xnew1,ynew1)

C:\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\fitpack2.pyc
in __call__(self, x, y, mth, dx, dy, grid)
    643                 z,ier = dfitpack.bispev(tx,ty,c,kx,ky,x,y)
    644                 if not ier == 0:
--> 645                     raise ValueError("Error code returned by
bispev: %s" % ier)
    646         else:
    647             # standard Numpy broadcasting

ValueError: Error code returned by bispev: 10
```

Any suggestion as to whether I am using the wrong functions or the right
function with wrong syntax, and how I may fix it is appreciated. Thank you.

#### UPDATE

I am running Python 2.7.9 and Scipy 0.14.0 (on Continuum Anaconda)
As posted on the Scipy mailing list [here](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2015-May/036536.html) the documentation seems confusing, being a mix of Scipy 0.14.0, and the next version. Can anybody suggest a workaround or the correct syntax for version 0.14.0.

#### UPDATE 2

tried

```
xnew1=np.array([3700.540199,3845.940199,3983.240199])
ynew1=np.array([1782.8611,1769.862,1694.862])
```

as suggested inj a comment but the error remains.

Comment: Tried your code and it worked. What scipy version do you use ?

Comment: You did use `xǹew` . Did you tried `xnew1` ?

Comment: It is interesting to see how colors can introduce artefacts. Try these colormaps and see the difference: `cm = plt.cm.BrBG
#cm = plt.cm.gray
#cm = plt.cm.cubehelix` Can you comment on that ?

Comment: +1 about colour ,Moritz I could not agree more. I wrote quite a bit about it http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mycarta/tutorials/blob/master/1408_Evaluate_and_compare_colormaps/How_to_evaluate_and_compare_colormaps.ipynb and often use one very similar to cubehelix. I noticed that with distance maps artifacts are even more pronounced, probably because it is strictly increasing data like the pyramid in my tutorial.

Comment: About the xnew, ynew instead of xnew1, ynew1, I must have copied that part from the older notebook, but I am nearly certain I had the latter in the newest. I'll have to check tomorrow in the office and also check the scipy version on that PC. I will add as an edit to the question accordingly.

Comment: Moritz, I tried again with xnew1, ynew1, still get the errors. I run I am running Python 2.7.9 and Scipy 0.14.0, see update. Can you think of a workaround?

Comment: I use scipy 15.01 within the conda environment (continuum analytics). What if you provide xnew1 and ynew1 as numpy array and not as list ?

Comment: Yep (see update). It did not work though.

Comment: what if you do `conda update scipy` ? I think it is a bug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77936/discussion-between-mycarta-and-moritz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax worked with RectBivariateSpline

```
x2 = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,c1)
y2 = np.linspace(ymin,ymax,r1)

f2 = sp.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(x2, y2, dstnc1.T,kx=1, ky=1)
```

I can then evaluate at new points with this:

```
out2 = f2.ev(xnew1,ynew1)
```

For interp2d I am stuck as I am not able to bypass firewall at my office to update Anaconda (Windows). I may be able at home on a Mac installation, in which case, if I get the syntax right, I will add to thsi answer.